# Execute bat-file from windows service without losing arguments

Tags: java, c#, batch-file, cmd, windows-services

I have to execute a bat-file within a C# windows service. The bat-file executes a jar-file with some arguments. That works without any problem.

But i noticed a **difference** between executing the bat-file:

**1. via the windows service:**
I am able to look up the start-arguments, when i query Win32_Process.

**2. not via the windows service (e.g. double click on bat-file):**
The start-arguments are not listed in the queries Win32_Process. But the jar-file within the bat was started correctly with the arguments...

How can i execute a bat-file from a c# windows service, so that i can query the details later on?

My current code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "BAT-PATH";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
```

Content of the bat-file:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=postgresql ^
    -Xmx1G -Xms1G ^
    -jar C:\PATH\TEST.jar
```

Comment: _"so that i can query the details later on"_ what does that mean exactly? you want to receive/check the output of jar file, is that the querying part? Also regarding the title... well it shouldn't lose arguments. If you run bat as `Process` it does what it does (so what is result for you?) and isn't it same thing as your **Point 1**? If worse comes to worse just parse the text of bat to strings and just run Java.exe itself as process with extracted strings as process-arguments

Comment: I want to query all running processes and check, if the specific jar is already running. I do a WMI query on Win32_Process and look at the CommandLine-Arguments. In Point 2 its working but not in Point 1 (because the CommandLine-Data is missing)